# Columns on the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I have troubles aligning rows/columns on the center of the page. I tried using margins, paddings and different aligns without any change. I don't know where I made the mistake. This CSS sheet is universal, but for that specific page, content is at the bottom.

For the rows and columns, I used the generator/already made sheets and edited for my needs, so maybe that's the problem?

**CSS:**

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box; /*universal box-sizing*/
}

body, html {
    margin-left: 0px;       /*zunanji odmik*/
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-color: #b3b3ff; /*hex value*/
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px; /*drugace nastavi auto browser*/
}   



.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

#h1{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    color: #6600ff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px; /*drugace nastavi auto browser*/
}

#h2 {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    color: #6600ff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

#ul{
    background-color: #6600ff;
}   


ul{
    list-style-type: none;  /*oznake v seznamu*/
    margin: 0;              /*to remove browser default settings*/
    padding: 0;             /*to remove browser default settings*/
    overflow: hidden;       /* ce bi b boxsu bilo prevec vsebine*/
    background-color: #1a1aff; /*barva navigacije*/

}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block; /*kot block elements naredi celotno areo clickable-ne samo tekst*/
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none; /*skrijes podcrtano besedilo*/

}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #000033; /*barva ozadja ko se postavimo z misko*/

}


.vsebina{
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.kartica{
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}   
/*naloga 2*/
.n2{width: 100%; } /*video*/

#n21{margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;} /*zunanji odmik clankov*/

.n22{
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
}   

.n23{ text-align: center; } /*pripis pod sliko*/



/*Naloga 4*/

input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid red;
   border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type=text]:focus, select:focus {
    border: 2px solid #555;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 4px;
    resize: none; /* prepreci spreminjanje polja*/
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

}   



/*naloga 3*/
#h3{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    color: #6600ff;
    text-align: center;
}


.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 10px 10px ;


  }

/* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
.row {
    margin: 0 -50px; 

}

/* Clear floats after the columns, postavi 3x2 */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}



.slika3{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="si">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ponudba</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>
    <div class="sticky">

            <h1 id="h1">Tilenova spletna stran </h1>

            <ul id="ul">
                <li><a href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
                <li><a href="ponudba.html">Ponudba</a></li>
                <li><a href="anketa.html">Anketa</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://estudij.um.si" target="_blank">Vaje</a></li>
            </ul>

    </div>


    <div class="vsebina">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="kartica">
                    <h3 id="h3">Mercedes-Benz</h3>
                        <img class="slika3" src="images/Mercedes.jpg" alt="Mercedes">
                        <div class="opis">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non risus ipsum. 
                            Curabitur in consectetur mauris, nec ultrices elit.
                        </div>

            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="kartica">
                    <h3 id="h3">Audi RS7 Sportback</h3>
                        <img class="slika3" src="images/Audi.jpg" alt="Audi">
                        <div class="opis">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non risus ipsum. 
                            Curabitur in consectetur mauris, nec ultrices elit.
                        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="kartica">
                    <h3 id="h3">Nissan 370Z</h3>
                        <img class="slika3" src="images/nissan.jpg" alt="nissan">
                        <div class="opis">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non risus ipsum. 
                            Curabitur in consectetur mauris, nec ultrices elit.
                        </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="kartica">
                    <h3 id="h3">Mini Cooper S</h3>
                        <img class="slika3" src="images/mini.jpg" alt="mini">
                        <div class="opis">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non risus ipsum. 
                            Curabitur in consectetur mauris, nec ultrices elit.
                        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="kartica">
                    <h3 id="h3">Jaguar F-type</h3>
                        <img class="slika3" src="images/jaguar.jpg" alt="jaguar">
                        <div class="opis">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non risus ipsum. 
                            Curabitur in consectetur mauris, nec ultrices elit.
                        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

            <div class="column">
                <div class="kartica">
                    <h3 id="h3">Tesla Model S</h3>
                        <img class="slika3" src="images/tesla.jpg" alt="tesla">
                        <div class="opis">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non risus ipsum. 
                            Curabitur in consectetur mauris, nec ultrices elit.
                        </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>

    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use 3 columns in your row, but set the width to 25%. That way you'll never have them centered. Either use 4 columns, or set the width to 33.33%.

Then also remove this part in your stylesheet:

```
.row {
    margin: 0 -50px; 
}
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4xf53vLe/

Comment: They are centered now. Thank you!